# Learning about Reprojection?

Tags: coordinate-system, references, reprojection-mathematics

I would like to expand my knowledge coordinate systems, projections and reprojecting data, with a view of writing a reprojection engine.

Could you provide me with some resources (books, websites, scrolls) on the maths behind coordinate systems and reprojecting data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The** reference (in the US, at least) is John Snyder's [Map Projections--A Working Manual](http://books.google.gr/books?id=nPdOAAAAMAAJ&dq=Map%20Projections--A%20Working%20Manual.&hl=en&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q=Map%20Projections--A%20Working%20Manual.&f=false).  The entire monograph is available as a Google book.

**Introductory sections give the theory.**  The theory is accessible to someone with a working knowledge of multivariate calculus.  Emphasis is on documenting formulas, primarily series expansions needed for subsequent calculations.  Detailed derivations of most formulas are *not* worked out.  (Snyder was not a mathematician and became interested in projections only later in life.  His emphasis--given this was written decades ago when one was lucky to have a Fortran compiler available and a few seconds of CPU time on the local mainframe--is on documenting formulas that could be converted to working code.)

**The bulk of the book** is devoted to describing 26 major projections organized by type: cylindrical, conic, azimuthal, "space map," pseudocylindrical, and miscellaneous.

Each description begins with a bulleted summary of properties and then about a page of historical information.  Following this are a narrative of the features of the projection--including a detailed line drawing with a lat-lon graticule--formulas for the sphere (projection and unprojection), and formulas for the ellipsoid.

**Appendices** include extensive numerical examples of the calculations (108 pages!) and some US-specific information about USGS projections and the State Plane coordinate system.

Comment: I had heard of this book about 6-7 years ago, and failed to get a copy.  Thank you very much for the FREE version!  I had a feeling you would come to my aid.  I don't want to lessen the thank you - except now I'll have to brush up on my calculus ;)

Comment: For those that can't get the book from Google Books, you can also get it directly from [USGS site](http://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395). Click on the 'View Document' Link to get the book as a pdf

Comment: Thanks, @Devdatta: that really is the link I was looking for.  I would expect it to have higher quality.